# Uncaught ReferenceError: someFunction is not defined

Tags: jquery

Why do I get **Uncaught ReferenceError: someFunction is not defined** here?:

#### HTML

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      someFunction();
  });
</script>
```

#### custom.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function someFunction() {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not in the global scope mate :-)

Comment: Your `someFunction()` is in a document ready function. Which means it wont be available until the document is ready. Take it out of this and it should be available on the global level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function someFunction() {
    // Do something
}
});
```

to :

```
function someFunction() {
    // Do something
}
```